# Updating nativescript to 6.1 ruined Scss compilation

Tags: angular, nativescript

Scss files are working as expected before the update but somehow not taking effect when I upgraded to 6.1.0. I really do not know where to start checking as I am not really familiar in webpack doings.

Where can I start checking?

Thanks!

PS. I use code sharing schematics.

Comment: Have you removed `nativescript-dev-sass` plugin and it's hooks?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a problem from the webpack. Do you get any errors or warnings into the console when you are debugging?

What's the version of your "nativescript-dev-webpack" package?

Upgrade to the current latest version (1.2.0) and it should use the right styling after that.

Don't forget to regenerate the webpack configuration and dependencies with

npm i nativescript-dev-webpack@latest --save-dev ./node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --deps --configs

For more details here is the documentation [Nativescript Upgrade Instructions](https://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions)